# how to auto calculate fields in inputs?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to auto calculate the discount amount by filling in two input fields but I don't know what am I doing wrong. What I want is that as I fill both inputs it appears the result in a third input.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="sale_price">Precio de Venta</label>
  <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="00.01" name="sale_price" class="form-control" id="saleP" onkeyup="discount();">
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="discount_percentage">Porcentaje de descuento (%)</label>
  <input type="number" name="discount_percentage" class="form-control" id="discountP" onkeyup="discount();">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="discount">Descuento</label>
  <input type="number" name="discount" placeholder="discount" class="form-control">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function discount() {
    var x;
    (document.getElementById('saleP').document.getElementById('discountP')) / 100 = x
  }
</script>
```

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do with 
       (document.getElementById('saleP').document.getElementById('discountP'))/100 = x

Comment: Please don't change the original question. If the answer you got is not working, leave a comment or ask a new question or add more questions to your original question. Changing the original question after you receive an answer makes the answers redundant or worse, irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your thought was behind the example line.

I've made the following changes:

- Added an `id` to the last `input` to target it
  `<input id="discount">`
- Get price input
  `const price = document.getElementById('saleP').value;`
- Get percentage value
  `const percentage = document.getElementById('discountP').value;`
- Calculate discount
  `const discount = price / 100 * percentage;`
- Set to last `input`
  `document.getElementById('discount').value = discount;`

```js
function discount(){
  const price = document.getElementById('saleP').value;
  const percentage = document.getElementById('discountP').value;
  const discount = price / 100 * percentage;
  document.getElementById('discount').value = discount; 
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="sale_price">Precio de Venta</label>
    <input type="number"  pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="00.01" name="sale_price" class="form-control" id="saleP" onkeyup="discount();">
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="discount_percentage">Porcentaje de descuento (%)</label>
    <input type="number" name="discount_percentage" class="form-control" id="discountP" onkeyup="discount();">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="discount">Descuento</label>
    <input type="number" name="discount" placeholder="discount" id="discount" class="form-control"  >
</div>
```

Comment: nice and *react*ive ;)

Comment: It's not new price you are calculating, but rather the discount amount.

Comment: Thanks but i get an odd error "discount is not a function" in my console

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried

Comment: @smac89 your right, I'll change the var name

Comment: @0stone0 i dont know why with the code snippet is working and in my code doesnt. Im putting the script in the same file as the html between script tags and below i have a script to validate the form and that one does works.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are not inputting `variable x` value into anything . If you add `onchange` event also, than it will work if user uses to increase decrease value using buttons.

**Instead of adding two events you can add `oninput` for dynamic changes whether user input values using keyboard or buttons**

```js
function discount() {
  var buyActualPrice = document.getElementById('saleP').value
  var cardDisc = document.getElementById('discountP').value
  var buyAtDiscAmount = (buyActualPrice * cardDisc) / 100
  document.getElementById('DiscountAmount').value = buyAtDiscAmount

  var priceAfterDisc = buyActualPrice - buyAtDiscAmount
  document.getElementById('PriceAfterDisc').innerHTML = priceAfterDisc
}

document.querySelectorAll("#DiscountAmount").forEach(discount)
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="sale_price">Price</label>
  <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="00.01" name="sale_price" class="form-control" id="saleP" oninput="discount();">
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="discount_percentage">Percentage disc. (%)</label>
  <input type="number" name="discount_percentage" class="form-control" id="discountP" oninput="discount();">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="discount">Discount Amount</label>
  <input type="number" name="discount" placeholder="discount" class="form-control" id="DiscountAmount">
</div>

<div>Price after discount applied : <span id="PriceAfterDisc"></span></div>
```

The last line in **JavaScript** is added so that if there are initial values than the results are shown at the start before any event

Comment: If you're going to use `onchange`, might as well remove `onkeyup`

Comment: Yes think of that first but when user input numbers using keyboard than the values don't change but user have to click outside of input to see changes

Comment: So added both of them

Comment: `oninput` can be used for that purpose . It will work for both `onkeyup` and `onchange`. As done in above code

Comment: Ah yes. That's even better

Comment: @Matuco you should also add `id` to your `name = discount` as used by user in answer . See changes in his `html` also the `id's` used

Comment: Not have the ability to comment so typed here