# Calculate input value with a fixed value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with a loop function.
Goal of the code is that people can enter a amount of goods they want to buy und the Js calculates a fixed value with the choosen amount.
then it should be printed out.
This should work in an html table with multible colums.

After the help of some people from the forum i have already a bit of code but i don't know how to write the code for a loop

Below there is the complete code. I used paragraphes to show the regarding code.

Thanks for help

```html
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="font-size: 16px;">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="page_type" content="np-template-header-footer-from-plugin">
    <title>Riesenhuber</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nicepage.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Riesenhuber.css" media="screen">
    <script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" defer=""></script>
    <script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="nicepage.js" defer=""></script>
    <meta name="generator" content="Nicepage 3.26.0, nicepage.com">
    <link id="u-theme-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i">
    
    
    <script type="application/ld+json">{
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Kulinarik"
    }</script>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    

    <script>
      document.querySelectorAll('.u-table-cell').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', event => {
          (function() {
                          const basePrice = document.getElementById("basePrice");
                          const quantityInput = document.getElementById("quantity");
                          const resOutput = document.getElementById("field_sum");
                          quantityInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
                            let currentQuantity = parseFloat(quantityInput.value);
                            let currentBasePrice = parseFloat(basePrice.getAttribute("value"));
                            resOutput.textContent = currentQuantity * currentBasePrice;
                          });
                        })()
          })
        })
    </script>
    
    
    
    
    

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#478ac9">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Riesenhuber">
    <meta property="og:description" content="">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  </head>
  <body class="u-body"><header class="u-clearfix u-grey-5 u-header u-sticky u-header" id="sec-d5e7"><div class="u-align-left u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <nav class="u-menu u-menu-dropdown u-offcanvas u-menu-1">
          <div class="menu-collapse" style="font-size: 1rem; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 700;">
            <a class="u-button-style u-custom-active-border-color u-custom-border u-custom-border-color u-custom-borders u-custom-hover-border-color u-custom-left-right-menu-spacing u-custom-padding-bottom u-custom-text-active-color u-custom-text-color u-custom-text-hover-color u-custom-top-bottom-menu-spacing u-nav-link u-text-active-palette-1-base u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="#">
              <svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#menu-hamburger"></use></svg>
              <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><symbol id="menu-hamburger" viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="width: 16px; height: 16px;"><rect y="1" width="16" height="2"></rect><rect y="7" width="16" height="2"></rect><rect y="13" width="16" height="2"></rect>
</symbol>
</defs></svg>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="u-custom-menu u-nav-container">
            <ul class="u-nav u-spacing-20 u-unstyled u-nav-1"><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-active-palette-1-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-custom-color-1 u-text-grey-90 u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="Startseite.html" style="padding: 10px;">Startseite</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-active-palette-1-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-custom-color-1 u-text-grey-90 u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="Übersicht.html" style="padding: 10px;">Übersicht</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-active-palette-1-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-custom-color-1 u-text-grey-90 u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="Riesenhuber.html" style="padding: 10px;">Riesenhuber</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-active-palette-1-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-custom-color-1 u-text-grey-90 u-text-hover-palette-2-base" href="Gasthaus-Teufel.html" style="padding: 10px;">GH Teufel</a>
</li></ul>
          </div>
          <div class="u-custom-menu u-nav-container-collapse">
            <div class="u-black u-container-style u-inner-container-layout u-opacity u-opacity-95 u-sidenav">
              <div class="u-inner-container-layout u-sidenav-overflow">
                <div class="u-menu-close"></div>
                <ul class="u-align-center u-nav u-popupmenu-items u-unstyled u-nav-2"><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Startseite.html" style="padding: 10px;">Startseite</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Übersicht.html" style="padding: 10px;">Übersicht</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Riesenhuber.html" style="padding: 10px;">Riesenhuber</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Gasthaus-Teufel.html" style="padding: 10px;">GH Teufel</a>
</li></ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-black u-menu-overlay u-opacity u-opacity-70"></div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <img class="u-image u-image-default u-image-1" src="images/Kreislogo.jpg" alt="" data-image-width="1189" data-image-height="1181">
        <a href="Login.html" data-page-id="26768470" class="u-active-none u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-hover-none u-none u-text-body-color u-btn-1">Logout</a>
        <p class="u-text u-text-default u-text-1">
          <span style="font-size: 1.25rem;">
            Mahlzeit&nbsp;
            <a>
              <?php
                echo($_SESSION['username']);
              ?>
            </a>
          </span>
          <br>
        </p>
      </div><style class="u-sticky-style" data-style-id="75d1">.u-sticky-fixed.u-sticky-75d1:before, .u-body.u-sticky-fixed .u-sticky-75d1:before {
borders: top right bottom left !important
}</style></header>
    <section class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-section-1" id="sec-7adc">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <div class="u-expanded-width u-tab-links-align-left u-tabs u-tabs-1">
          <ul class="u-border-2 u-border-palette-1-base u-spacing-10 u-tab-list u-unstyled" role="tablist">
            <li class="u-tab-item" role="presentation">
              <a class="active u-active-palette-1-base u-button-style u-grey-10 u-tab-link u-text-active-white u-text-black u-tab-link-1" id="link-tab-0da5" href="#tab-0da5" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-0da5" aria-selected="true">Gebäck</a>
            </li>
            <li class="u-tab-item" role="presentation">
              <a class="u-active-palette-1-base u-button-style u-grey-10 u-tab-link u-text-active-white u-text-black u-tab-link-2" id="link-tab-14b7" href="#tab-14b7" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-14b7" aria-selected="false">Snacks</a>
            </li>
            <li class="u-tab-item" role="presentation">
              <a class="u-active-palette-1-base u-button-style u-grey-10 u-tab-link u-text-active-white u-text-black u-tab-link-3" id="link-tab-2917" href="#tab-2917" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-2917" aria-selected="false">Mehlspeisen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="u-tab-item u-tab-item-4" role="presentation">
              <a class="u-active-palette-1-base u-button-style u-grey-10 u-tab-link u-text-active-white u-text-black u-tab-link-4" id="tab-93fc" href="#link-tab-93fc" role="tab" aria-controls="link-tab-93fc" aria-selected="false">Getränke</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="u-tab-content">
            <div class="u-container-style u-tab-active u-tab-pane u-white u-tab-pane-1" id="tab-0da5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="link-tab-0da5">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-1">
                <div class="u-expanded-width u-table u-table-responsive u-table-1">
                  <table class="u-table-entity">
                    <colgroup>
                      <col width="20%">
                      <col width="2.1%">
                      <col width="22%">
                      <col width="21.7%">
                      <col width="34.2%">
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody class="u-table-alt-grey-5 u-table-body">
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <b>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-1"><b>Produkt</b><span style="font-weight: 700;"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-3"><b>Einzelpreis</b></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-4"><b>Menge</b></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-5"><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
                        </b>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Kornspitz</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <p value="1.39" id="basePrice">1,39 €</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <form id="Menge">
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="quantity" value="0" step="1.0">
                          </form>
                        </td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <form id="sum">
                            <p><output id="field_sum" for="quantity">0</output> €</p>
                          </form>
                        </td>
                      </tr>


                      
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 2</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <p value="5.39" id="basePrice">5,39 €</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <form id="Menge">
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="quantity" value="0" step="1.0">
                          </form>
                        </td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <form id="sum">
                            <p><output id="field_sum" for="quantity">0</output> €</p>
                          </form>
                        </td>
                      </tr>


                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 2</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <form id="Menge">
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="quantity" value="0" step="1.0">
                          </form>
                        </td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <form id="sum">
                            <p><span>Gesamt:</span> <output id="field_sum" for="quantity">0</output> €</p>
                          </form>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 2</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <form id="quantity">
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="quantity" value="0" step="1.0">
                          </form>
                        </td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">
                          <form id="sum">
                            <p><span>Gesamt:</span> <output id="field_sum" for="quantity">0</output> €</p>
                          </form>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <p>Hello</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="u-container-style u-tab-pane u-white u-tab-pane-2" id="tab-14b7" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="link-tab-14b7">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-2">
                <div class="u-expanded-width u-table u-table-responsive u-table-2">
                  <table class="u-table-entity">
                    <colgroup>
                      <col width="20%">
                      <col width="2.1%">
                      <col width="22%">
                      <col width="21.7%">
                      <col width="34.2%">
                    </colgroup>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    <tbody class="u-table-alt-grey-5 u-table-body">
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-26">Produkt<span style="font-weight: 700;"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-28">Einzelpreis</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-29">Menge</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-30">Gesamtpreis</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell"> Chillistangerl</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"> € 1,39</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 2</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 3</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 56px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 4</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-container-style u-tab-pane u-white u-tab-pane-3" id="tab-2917" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="link-tab-2917">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-3">
                <div class="u-expanded-width u-table u-table-responsive u-table-3">
                  <table class="u-table-entity">
                    <colgroup>
                      <col width="20%">
                      <col width="2.1%">
                      <col width="22%">
                      <col width="21.7%">
                      <col width="34.2%">
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody class="u-table-alt-grey-5 u-table-body">
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-51">Produkt<span style="font-weight: 700;"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-53">Einzelpreis</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-54">Menge</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-55">Gesamtpreis</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell"> Chillistangerl</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"> € 1,39</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 2</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 3</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 56px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 4</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-container-style u-tab-pane u-white u-tab-pane-4" id="link-tab-93fc" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-93fc">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-4">
                <div class="u-expanded-width u-table u-table-responsive u-table-4">
                  <table class="u-table-entity">
                    <colgroup>
                      <col width="20%">
                      <col width="2.1%">
                      <col width="22%">
                      <col width="21.7%">
                      <col width="34.2%">
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody class="u-table-alt-grey-5 u-table-body">
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-76">Produkt<span style="font-weight: 700;"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-78">Einzelpreis</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-79">Menge</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-80">Gesamtpreis</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell"> Chillistangerl</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"> € 1,39</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 2</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 55px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 3</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height: 56px;">
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 4</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell">Description</td>
                        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="u-text u-text-1">
          <span style="font-size: 1.25rem; font-weight: 700;">Gesamtpreis:&nbsp;</span>
          <span style="font-size: 1.25rem;"></span>
        </p>
        <a href="https://nicepage.com/wordpress-themes" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-palette-1-base u-btn-1">AGB</a>
        <a href="https://nicepage.com/website-builder" class="u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-custom-color-1 u-btn-2">Bestellen<br>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
    
    
    <footer class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-stick-footer u-grey-80 u-stick-footer" id="sec-1243"><div class="u-align-left u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1"></div></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to write a js script for this. The script would get the value of your input, calculate and display the result where you want in the html.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69120941/16846346 : This may help you have to just define a fixed price (in answer I provided to be entered by user) and remove some fields and have change according to it

Comment: "*i don't know how to combine the js script with html*" If this is truly the case, you should probably be seeking out a bit more fundamental-level literature regarding the use of JavaScript in-browser. Have you added this code to a `<script></script>` block? What happened when you did? Where are you trying to invoke the `calculate()` function?

Comment: Yes i did that but there is no effect on the webpage
would it be a problem to post the complete code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution :

```html
<tr style="height: 55px;">
  <b>
                        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-1"><b>Produkt</b><span style="font-weight: 700;"></span>
  </td>
  <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
  <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-3"><b>Einzelpreis</b></td>
  <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-4"><b>Menge</b></td>
  <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-5"><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
  </b>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 55px;">
  <td class="u-table-cell">Kornspitz</td>
  <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
  <td class="u-table-cell">
    <p value="1.39" id="basePrice">1.39 €</p>
  </td>
  <td class="u-table-cell">
    <form id="Menge">
      <input type="number" min="0" id="quantity" value="0" step="1.0">
    </form>
  </td>
  <td class="u-table-cell">
    <form id="sum">
      <p><output id="field_sum" for="quantity">0</output> €</p>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
<script>
(function() {
  const basePrice = document.getElementById("basePrice");
  const quantityInput = document.getElementById("quantity");
  const resOutput = document.getElementById("field_sum");
  quantityInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
    let currentQuantity = parseFloat(quantityInput.value);
    let currentBasePrice = parseFloat(basePrice.getAttribute("value"));
    resOutput.textContent = currentQuantity * currentBasePrice;
  });
})()
</script>
```

But here are some warnings about some things that will probably cause you problems in a near future.

**Don't** save data as a number with a **","** inside it. Always use **"."** instead

If you save some data in the attribute value in a p. That won't be accessible by doing `element.value`.

If I was you, I'll do something like `<p data-value="1.39"></p>`. And then use `element.dataset.value` to get/set it

Comment: thanks for that 
and how can i link the Js document with the html doc ?

Comment: You can either put it directly in a script tag to start (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp). Or include it in a file like so :(https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp)

Comment: I'm sorry i cant make it work

is it a problem to post the complete code ?

Comment: @Setzi138 I've updated the answer. I don't know if you've seen but I have added an id attribute to your p tag with the base price

Comment: do i have to write the script after every column?

Comment: No, don't do that. You could do a loop that iterate throught all of your column to add the event listener to all input. But to help you with that, I'll need more details about your html document. For now, here a doc on the for each loop (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and here a documentation on the getElementByClassName (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Comment: it works for the first row in the table but not for the following ?

Comment: Yeah, because in the script, we select only the first elements, if you need this script to work for a table, you'll need to include it into a loop. But first you should learn how loop works and how to select multiple elements at the same time, that'll make it easier for you to do it